# What's the meaning of "_FORM" in ModelState?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I was going through the AccountController class (the default one). I noticed that "**_FORM**" is used at many places with the *ModelState*. For, isntance:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("username", "You must specify a username.");
        }

if (!String.Equals(password, confirmPassword, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "The new password and confirmation password do not match.");
        }
```

It's easy to tell the meaning for the username (as it is for for email, password, and confirmpassword). but what's "_FORM"? Has it a special meaning? I did not see where it is defined.

Thank for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have an input element with `name="_FORM"` this could be used to just add a model error which will be shown in the error summary but no inputs would appear in red.

Comment: This is exactly right.  The name "_FORM" is just a dummy so that it appears in the summary, but not in any field validation message.  The MVC 2 templates use the empty string ("") instead of "_FORM", but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It has meaning in MVC 2 as a way to specify a validation summary error, as described above.

But in MVC 3 and later, you need to pass an empty string as the key parameter to ModelState.AddModelError(). Passing "_FORM" to denote a validation summary error doesn't seem to work any longer.[See this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818219/asp-net-mvc-html-validationsummarytrue-does-not-display-model-errors).