# How to Display Validation Error Messages on an ASP.NET MVC Page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am pretty new to ASP.NET and C# I have spent the day learning the basics of the ASP.NET Membership provider I have built all my validator but are getting stuck at outputting my error message on the page.

```
private void LogCreateUserError(MembershipCreateStatus status, string username)
{
    string reasonText = status.ToString();

    switch (status)
    {
        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateProviderUserKey:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:

            reasonText = "The user details you entered are already registered.";
            break;

        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidProviderUserKey:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:

            reasonText = string.Format("The {0} provided was invalid.", status.ToString().Substring(7));
            break;
        default:
            reasonText = "Due to an unknown problem, we were not able to register you at this time";
            break;

    }

   //CODE TO WRITE reasonText TO THE HTML PAGE ??

}
```

What is the best way to output the varible result onto the page as I have relied upon the built in ASP:Validators until now.

Comment: Is this using ASP.NET MVC or WebForms? Also, do you have any specific controls on the page that you would like the status to be shown in?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC, I have not put any controls in place for it as I am a little unsure what controls it could write to. 

Would <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage"/> be appropriate ? or am i drifting in the wrong direction.

Comment: What class does that private method belong to - the controller? Could you post the code for the controller action that is calling it?

Comment: Ps. With ASP.NET MVC, using anything with `runat="server"` is drifting completely down the wrong direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**MVC**

See for a good example...

[ASP.NET MVC Html.ValidationSummary(true) does not display model errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818219/asp-net-mvc-html-validationsummarytrue-does-not-display-model-errors)

Basically, you need to propagate the error *message* and also that fact that there *is* an error to your view from your controller.  [ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror.aspx) will take care of both of these tasks for you.

You can then use [ValidationExtensions.ValidationSummary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary.aspx) to display.

**Webforms**

You don't *have* to use a validator for this.  Most people don't.  A simple styled DIV should work well.

eg.

```
<div id="errorMessageDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

Notice the `runat` parameter.

Now in your code-behind you can try

```
errorMessageDiv.innerHTML = "some error message";
```

If you really want to use a validator checkout...

http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2008/12/12/putting-messages-into-a-validationsummary-control-from-code.aspx

Basically you set the *ErrorMessage* and *isValid* parameters to the related validator in the code behind.  The related *ValidationSummary* should display the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation summary or you can use a label control to display the error message

Answer (score -1):

If using WebForms you might use a Label control and set the '.Text' property of it with your result.  Or a Panel control.  Or a UserControl specifically for outputting error messages (this is what I do) that you can add to your MasterPage.