# ASP.NET Beginner: Form roundtrip with model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm beggining to learn Asp.net and C# for about a week. Until now, I've been developing in PHP and Symfony so this is quite a big transition for me. I'm learning Asp.net from a book ASP.NET MVC 4 in Action.

I'm trying to validate a model but I can't find anything online that will help a newbie like me. A model validates a contact form with name, email and a message. Simple, right?. Not for me.

This is the model...

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The name has to be provided, even a fictional one")]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address has to be provided, even a invalid one")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { set; get; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Don't be lazy. Write a message")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Message { set; get; }
}
```

I have a controller called ContactController. It has these actions...

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ContactModel contactModel = new ContactModel();
    return View(contactModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult SaveModel(ContactModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Also, here is a Razor template that shows the model in the UI.

```
<div class="UI__Main  Main__Contact">
<h1 class="UI__Main--SectionHeader">Contact the administrators of Life</h1>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveModel", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="Form  Form__Contact" }))
    {
        <div class="Form__Row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class="Form__Label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class="Form__TextType  Form__TextInput" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="Form__Row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "Form__Label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "Form__TextType  Form__TextInput" })
        </div>

            <div class="Form__Row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, new { @class="Form__Label" })
                @Html.TextArea("Message", new { @class = "Form__TextType  Form__TextArea" })
            </div>

        <div class="Form__Row  Submit__Row">
            <input id="Submit__Button" type="submit" value="Send" />
        </div>
    }
```

When the user submits the form, the form would have to go to `SaveModel` action in `ContactController` but action attribute of `<form>` is blank `action=""` so i don't think it's even going to `Save Model`. Also, validation messages are not displayed. I tried the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` but that only displays text even when i don't submit the form.

I don't even know what the problem is here let alone find it.

If anyone has any suggestions, tutorials, articles or something like that about creating form in asp.net mvc 4 and razor, please give it to me.

I've read this [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation) but that doesn't solve my problem. I also found [this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818219/asp-net-mvc-html-validationsummarytrue-does-not-display-model-errors) and [this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830823/how-to-display-validation-error-messages-on-an-asp-net-mvc-page) but as i said, I'm a newbie and I really don't understand the problems in those questions.

EDIT:

Here are the routes of the app...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action="Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "contact",
    defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "Contact" }
);
```

Comment: Have you implemented any extra routes, besides the default one?

Comment: I've made an edit. ContactController/ContactAction is called with a static route but , my guess is that model validation has to go to another action, which is SaveModel action in ContactController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `action` stays empty because the MVC framework can not resolve an url for the given controller+action. You have to explicitly define an url in the routing table:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "contact/send-form",
    defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "SaveModel" }
);
```

Or you can alternatively generate a generic fallback route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

which will result in that all your controller/actions are available as direct urls.

Alternatively; you can also use [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) so your routes are defined directly at the actions, less looking here & there. To do so you have to:

- add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in the `RegisterRoutes.cs`
- append attributes to your actions `[Route("contact")]`

You can also re-use the same route if the http method differs:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("contact"}
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ContactModel contactModel = new ContactModel();
    return View(contactModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("contact")]
public ViewResult Contact(ContactModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid){
    //persist your contact form, redirect somewhere
  }
  return View(model);//re-render the form with error messages
}
```

Comment: YES. That was it. Thank you very much. The error message displayes nicely.

Comment: Usage a `route` attributes are only essential if you have to use in a case when url must have other form than wrote in Route map. Otherwise is reccomended to avoid this parameter. This way determines rigorous an approach to your project.