# MVC3 Add & Display Message through ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, modelstate

I have a scenario like i need to display error message which is coming from DB on Edit [GET] request.

I know this can be done if request type is of [POST], but how can we do this in [GET] request.

Same Code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(Int64 ID)
      {
         tblSample1 model = GetData(ID);
         ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError(model.Username, "Invalid Username provided.");
         return View("~/Views/Sample1/_Edit.cshtml", model);
      }
```

`[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(tblSample1 model)
  {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           ......
           ......
        }
  }`

Comment: why full postback for such validations and why not return validation through json

Comment: I think this link might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739362/modelstate-addmodelerror-how-can-i-add-an-error-that-isnt-for-a-property

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should still work. The first argument to `AddModelError` is the key. You're passing it the value of the property `Username`.. which won't work. What you want is to pass the property name as the key:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Invalid Username provided.");
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^ Username property of model
```

Of course this must be coupled with a `ValidationSummary` or `ValidationMessage` in your view.

Comment: thanks buddy, i think now i know what silly mistake i was doing.