# Model with Required attribute doesn't show any error messages for bad user input

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I have an application in which there is a user and retailer account. I want to implement validation of retailer registration form. I made a model for retailer with Required Connotation but the page still doesn't show any messages for wrong inputs. Any suggestion how I can achieve my goal. Im using Asp.net MVC

```
[PropertiesMustMatch("Password", "ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public class RegisterStore
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Store Name is Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Store Name")]
    public string Store_Name { get; set; }
  .
  .       
    Similarly other properties ...
  .
  .

}
```

The code for View is like

```
 <h2>Create a Store Account</h2>
<p>
    Use the form below to create a new account. 
</p>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Retailer Information</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Store_Name) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Store_Name) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Store_Name) %>
        </div>
        .

        ... Similar DIVs for other properties ....
        .
        .
        .
        .

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Next" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

The code for controller is like

```
  [HttpPost()]
    public ActionResult RetailerRegisteration(RegisterStore storeModel)
    {
        //ViewData["genders"] = Genders;
        Debug.WriteLine("Started RetailerRegisteration");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeModel.UserName))
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter Username");     
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeModel.Store_Name))
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter a store name");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeModel.Email) || !storeModel.Email.Contains("@"))
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter a valid e-mail address!");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeModel.Password))
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter a Password");
        if(! storeModel.Password.Equals(storeModel.ConfirmPassword))
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The Passwords must match");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           ... Create Store Account ....

        }
```

Comment: When you say "wrong inputs," do you mean fields left empty by the user?

Comment: Yes @Harvey ..field left blank

Answer (score 2):

Try  `<%: Html.ValidationSummary(false) %>` to show all errors.

Also, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818219/asp-net-mvc-html-validationsummarytrue-does-not-display-model-errors) question.

Comment: You mean set it to true?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using client validation or server-side validation only?

If you're checking server-side, are you checking `ModelState.IsValid` on POST? The validation won't actually fire until you check this property.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVC2 or MVC3? There are subtle differences between the two. In either case, you must include the appropriate jQuery or Ajax validation JavaScript scripts to get client side validation.