# Mvc 4 validation summary errors not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having trouble displaying validation summary, I only want to display errors in validation summary, not beside the field.
In my view i have,

```
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>m.Name)
```

in my controller i have

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Name",
                                "name is required");
```

Am i not supposed to get a validation error message? at the top? 
I don't get what i am missing...

I am also including these script files..
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818219/asp-net-mvc-html-validationsummarytrue-does-not-display-model-errors

Comment: I tried that solution before i posted this question. I don't know what i am missing

Comment: Hmm, I don't think they are conflicting, but you don't need `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>m.Name)` if you just want the summary.

Comment: Also have you tried looking at the actual source returned from the server to see if the error message is there?  It is possible some CSS is causing it not to appear.

Comment: I looked in the css, the div tag is there but no text in the validation....I don't know what i am missing

Comment: Can you update the question with the steps you are taking where you expect the validation error to show up?

Comment: show us your View, ActionResult, then we will be able to help you...

Comment: make sure your button has type 'submit' and not 'button'

Comment: Please post out your html that is generated by `@Html.ValidationSummary`.

Answer (score 30):

Try

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

so that it will not exclude property errors.

OR

Try the method @xurca linked which is to add the model error with an empty key so it is not tied to a specific property.

```
ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "name is required");
```

Comment: I'm working on two projects at the same time, VS '12 and VS '13.  At any rate, I had no issues in '13 with the default template, but setting TRUE to FALSE solved it for me in the '12 project (as per your post).  At any rate, thanks for the post.

Answer (score 2):

If you custom named your field like

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {  id = "staffSearchFilterName", value = "", **Name = "staffSearchFilterName"** })
```

then you have to use

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("staffSearchFilterName")
```

Answer (score 2):

If your @Html.ValidationSummary() call is in a Partial view, DON'T pass data into the partial view like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_YourForm", Model,  new ViewDataDictionary { { "Submit", true }})
```

Instead, add the key value pair to Html.ViewData collection first:

```
@{
    Html.ViewData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,object>("Submit",true));
}
```

then call the partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("_YourForm", Model, Html.ViewData)
```

this will allow the ModelState to propagate to the partial view properly.