# Having troubles adding jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Basically I'm used to starting my ASP.NET MVC4 projects with the Internet template. However this time I tried out with the Basic template.
Now, I'm trying to manually add jQuery validation:
I've installed the NuGet package jQuery.validation and have included it in my bundleconfig and _layout file.

Here's my bundleconfig:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

And here's how I include it in _layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Here are the js files being loaded per request:

```
http://localhost:10815/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js
http://localhost:10815/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
http://localhost:10815/Scripts/jquery.validate.js
http://localhost:10815/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

In my controller I check if ModelState.IsValid and if not I return the view with the model - I've debugged the method and know for sure that the modelstate has errors.

And finally in my view file I have included:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Which produces the following HTML output:

```
<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>
```

My issue is the fact that the validation summary doesn't change when I the controller returns the view - I don't know what's wrong though - what am I missing?

PROBLEM SOLVED - I used ajax which I've turned off now - works fine without ajax. I guess the validationsummary doesnt get reloaded thus no html is updated.

Comment: Are you posting data initially to this method as it's a HttpPost type, or is there a corresponding Get method you are initially rendering?

Comment: @ianaldo21

Im posting the data to the post method. Initially I'm loading the view through an empty get method that just returns the view.

Comment: Please don't put the solution inside your question. Instead, post the answer below as soon as the site allows.

Answer (score 0):

For the validation to work, you need to have a model property with the name of `Test error`

EDIT:

You need to place data annotations in your model.

```
  public class Contact
    {
        [Required]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Nevermind the manually added error - I've removed it and I still get the same result even though I enter invalid input in the form.

Comment: I already have data annotations - I KNOW for a fact that it catches the errors - however it is not being displayed in the view.

Comment: Did you use `TextBoxFor` to render the fields of the form?

Comment: I've added TextBoxFor - it still doesn't show in validationsummary but it now displays an error in @Html.ValidationMessageFor


I wonder why it doesn't get displayed in validationsummary though

Comment: Ahh apparently it doesn't work when the form is AJAX - I didn't know that - thanks for your assistance anyways

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819178/1316931) answer. If you define a key there must be a match in the model.

Comment: Nevermind the manually added error - I've removed it and I still get the same result even though I enter invalid input in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I used ajax which I've turned off now - works fine without ajax. I guess the validationsummary doesnt get reloaded thus no html is updated.