# MVC3 ValidationSummary Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validationsummary

I am trying to create validation summary in MVC but I am not getting how to create validation summary. I have created Validation summary in **asp.net** by using Validation summary control.

I want to display error summary in Bullet list. So, how  can I create it in **MVC3**? What is a better way to create it? Is there any example or demo?

I want to display like this at the top of View.

**Please correct the following error**

- **First Name required**
- **Last Name required**

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818219/asp-net-mvc-html-validationsummarytrue-does-not-display-model-errors

Comment: @Curt I want to display the error list at the top of page in bullet list format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
@Html.ValidationSummary() in .cshtml page.
```

and Check ModelState in Controller like this

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = Model.Save();
                if (result)
                {
                    //ViewData["MessageFromServer"] = "<p>Saved Successfully<p>";
                   return  RedirectToAction("Index");

                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["MessageFromServer"] = "Error while saving";

                }
            }


                return View("Create", Model);
```

you will see the errors in page.

Comment: Thank you. It works. No need to add ViewData. I added only `@Html.ValidationSummary()`

Comment: use place holder attribute. it dose not work on old versions of ie. refer link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: I tried it. It works in TextBoxFor control but not in EditorFor control.