# MVC 4 Show validation Summary outside the Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am developing a web application in MVC 4 Asp.Net C#. I have a design which showing all the error at top of the page. But when using Data Annotations I am unable to show validation summary outside the form. Can any one please help me out to overcome this issue thans in advance. 
Following is my Senario

My forms look like this

```
    @model ChrisFinnerty.Models.LocalPasswordModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Change Password";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "FormChangePassword", @role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal well"}))
    {

        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <h2>Change Password</h2>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword, new {@class = "form-control"})

        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new {@class = "form-control"})

        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new {@class = "form-control"})

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change Password</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.history.go(-1) ">Cancel</button>
     }
```

But I want like that show validation summary outside the form in notification div

```
        @model ChrisFinnerty.Models.LocalPasswordModel
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Change Password";
        }

        @Html.ValidationSummary() //*****Just want to add it here its not working****

        @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "FormChangePassword", @role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal well"}))
        {
            <h2>Change Password</h2>
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword, new {@class = "form-control"})

            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new {@class = "form-control"})

            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new {@class = "form-control"})

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change Password</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.history.go(-1) ">Cancel</button>
         }
```

Comment: Just move the div into the form and your problem is solved... Not sure what the difference is.

Comment: You can also achieve this thing using CSS.

Comment: Form is at bottom of page and notification div is at the top of page. its design limitation I cant add notification div into form its disturb the layout of page :'(

Comment: DataAnootations will bind the error messages to those particular input elements(so it will be shown with the input element itself). If all you want to show is a list of errors try using a error message pop up http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-alert-windows-prompts/ you can use something from these

Comment: Dear I just want to show @Html.validationsummary() outside the form

Comment: @WaqasIdrees have u seen inbuilt application given in VS2010 for mvc3 in it for LogOn.cshtml page there is exact implementation as u want i.e. Valicationsummary is outside form

Comment: Can you all people please check it now I improve the layout of my question

Comment: @Nitin Varpe Let me check

Comment: @NitinVarpe you right but they implement with the static message like this

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

Comment: You can add `ModelState.AddModelError` at controller side and add any erros you want. Have u seen controller action for LogOn

Comment: @NitinVarpe I added there that why its working inside the form

Comment: didnt get u! have u tested in that demo app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45871/discussion-between-waqas-idrees-and-nitin-varpe)

Comment: Did you ever get this question answered? I have the same issue with MVC 4.. Sure I can add @Html.ValidationSummary() to each form, but it's silly. I want to design validation message handling once and have it just work rather than putting @Html.ValidationSummary() in each form

Comment: @eaglei22 You can achieve this only by using JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

Just add `@Html.ValidationSummary()` out side the form. I had same problem see this. [MVC3 ValidationSummary Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283480/mvc3-validationsummary-control)

See this example http://mahaafifi.blogspot.in/2011/12/multiple-validation-summary-at-single.html

Comment: But when I add the @Html.ValidationSummary() tag outside the form its shows nothing

Only showing error when we write this inside form tag

Comment: I did same implementation. it works from my side. check that link in my ans.

Comment: I checked but not worked and in that link it is not mentioned that we are able to write validation summary outside the form.

I checked at my side but its not working

Comment: @WaqasIdrees Why you are want it outside the form ? I checked my code it is inside the form.

Comment: Because in all pages I show the error message at the top of the page and my some form is at bottom of page but I want to show error at top page just like other pages in my application

Comment: you can add it above `<h2>change password</h2>`

Comment: you are not understanding my requirement yet I want to add @html.Validationsummay any where else in my page any where not just right top of form any where